# What is it about some questions that makes them so popular?

Tags: discussion

I am curious if anyone has come up with what makes a question popular.

The question that triggered this curiosity is [How to prevent pictures from being downloaded by right-clicking on them or Inspecting the web page?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/132996/how-to-prevent-pictures-from-being-downloaded-by-right-clicking-on-them-or-inspe) - 4k views in 2 days, 8 answers and my answer has 25 up votes.

To me it doesn't seem like a special question, yet it seems to have touched something in a lot of readers.  Is it because compared to many questions a lot of readers might know something about this?  Is it because it is something that affects many people?  Could it be just a bit of an answering frenzy, where because it is modified so often, the question is bumped so it is read more, so it is modified which bumps it, etc etc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That question became a Hot Network Question, which can be seen from its [timeline](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/posts/132996/timeline#history_9b8c39f8-a079-47e5-9254-f0f0c00c0778):

[image]

[Hot Network Questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/hot-questions/info) are visible on *every* site in the network, drawing much more attention than just regular Webmasters visitors. That explains the number of views; thanks to the [association bonus](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141648/295232), a good deal of those users can upvote (but not downvote!) the question and its answers.

Comment: I'll bet that you are one of the few users that can down vote on nearly every site.  I always appreciate your edits on Webmasters, BTW.

Comment: Thank you. I'm probably the only one apart from SE staff (diamonds give you downvote power as well).

Comment: Do you know what the current algorithm for hot network questions is?   The most plausible that I've been able to come up with is that SE is using a variant of the scoring algorithm proposed here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/295583/limit-the-number-of-questions-per-site-in-the-hot-network-questions-list/295701#295701

Comment: We don't know exactly; I did some [research](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/318108/295232) a while ago.